# Installing QSTK in anaconda windows

Tags: python, anaconda

i cannot get anaconda to install qstk. here is what i typed in cmd prompt.

```
conda install QSTK
```

But i guess that does not work because the continuum repos dont include QSTK. the error i get is No packages found matching qstk.
i checked the repos by typing the following in cmd prompt:

```
conda info
```

That told be the repo was continuum repo. so i checked http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/index.html  and found that QSTK is not there.

How do i install qstk in anaconda? I downloaded the qstk tar.gz file but i dont know how to install with it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try install it with `pip install qstk`?

If you have only one python version installed at your computer it should work.

Comment: anaconda is coming with pip, so you can use anaconda's version instead of the OS's version

Answer (score 0):

Using `easy_install -U QSTK` in anaconda cmd prompt worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In conda virtual environment I used following commands to install the package successfully:

```
1- pip install qstk
2- conda install matplotlib
```